# Show only a few characters from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this simple helper (in Rails app):

```
def shortener(text, text_length = nil)
  if text_length.nil?
    text_size = 60
  else
    text_size = text_length
  end

  #text_size = 60 if text_length.nil? => return the same error as above

  if text.length.to_i > text_size.to_i # HERE IS THE ISSUE
    return "#{text[0..(text_size-5)]}..."
  else
    return text
  end
end
```

However, I am getting this error:

> undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass

Why am I getting this error? Both parameters exist and are integers.

Comment: While the accepted answer is great (and I would recommend doing so), it's not the answer to the original question.
Calling `length` fails ==> You're calling `length` on `text`. Hence, `text` is `nil` (you're not passing any text into `short()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are using Rails, I recommend you to use Rails built-in helper `truncate`

```
truncate("And they found that many people were sleeping better.", length: 25, omission: '... (continued)')
```

For more information, refer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you want to roll your own method instead of using the built-in `truncate`:

```
def shortener(text = "", text_length = 60)
  "#{text[0...text_length]}..."
end
```

Comment: You forget ... after the shorten text

Answer (score 0):

It means `text` is `nil`. Use `caller` to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because `text` is passed as `nil`.

In order for it to behave like a normal text renderer in rails, you might want to do this:

```
  def shortener(text, text_length = 60)
    text ||= ''

    if text.length.to_i > text_length.to_i
      return "#{text[0..(max_text_length-5)]}..."
    else
      return text
    end
  end
```

Comment: why not just def shortener(text='', text_length=nil)

Comment: @AbrahamP, if you do that, then if the caller does something like `shortener(nil)`, it will still fail, as your placeholder only works if the parameter is not passed, and not if it is passed and is `nil`